# Implementing AZURE portal log off using Javascript

Tags: logout, azureportal

I log into my organization AZURE portal and access all my applications. I click on my application and that application page opens in a new tab. I added a button to log out using JAVASCRIPT.

```
    function Logout() {            
        window.location.href = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri";
    }
```

When I click this logout button, the application logs off. Then I open another window and enter the application url. The application does not ask for log in. Instead it opens the application and I can access the entire application.

How to log off the user and make them enter the credentials next time they open the application after they log off.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [single sign-out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript#sign-out) to log off the app.

```
const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'your_app_id',
        redirectUri: "your_app_redirect_uri", //defaults to application start page
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "your_app_logout_redirect_uri"
    }
}

const myMsal = new UserAgentApplication(config);

myMsal.logout();
```